# Determine copper thicknesses for multi layer PCB

Tags: pcb, copper, stack-up

When deciding PCB stack-up generally accept the manufacturer suggestions. Especially they calculate the track impedance more accurate. For my last design I checked the guideliness for the FPGA (Microsemi's IGLOO2) the one I used. I have seen the stack-up Microsemi used in development board. Generally for copper thickness I use 1/2 Oz (H) for outer lates or 1 Oz for internal.  The Microsemi's stack-up  has H (1/2 Oz) and Q(1/4 Oz). What is the point here? Why should I use tinner copper?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage to having thinner copper would be because this allows you to have slightly smaller traces. The thicker the copper is on the board, the wider you have to make your traces.

Comment: It's worth adding a reminder that the outer layers will typically get an additional ~20 um of copper added in the plating step, so even if you start with 1/2-oz (18 um) you'll end up with nearly the same thickness as 1-oz. If you start with 1/4-oz you'll end up with something like 3/4-oz after plating.